# What is the correct way to use PHP array_diff?

Tags: php

I am having trouble understanding the correct way to use `array_diff` in PHP and whether or not it is the correct function to use in my case.

`$array1 =`

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1457543
    [1] => 1457544
    [2] => 1461778
    [3] => 1465640
    [4] => 1473801
    [5] => 1474814
    [6] => 1474815
    [7] => 1475227
    [8] => 1478144
    [9] => 1479478
    [10] => 1480843
)
```

`$array2 =`

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1336623
    [1] => 1457543
    [2] => 1457544
    [3] => 1461778
    [4] => 1465640
    [5] => 1468007
    [6] => 1474814
    [7] => 1474815
    [8] => 1478144
    [9] => 1479478
    [10] => 1480843
)
```

I want to make sure that all numbers present in `$array2` are also present in `$array1`.

I would use `array_diff($array2, $array1);`. Is this correct?

Does `array_diff` ignore the keys, because I need it to do that, and just check the values, because the keys won't usually be the same in both arrays for the same value as there are missing numbers which is the point in this code to locate.

Comment: Have you seen [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php)?

Comment: Use `array_diff_assoc`

Comment: the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) give a really good explination.

Comment: @RowlandShaw Yes, but I'm not clear on the keys. Does it totally ignore them, and just check values regardless of keys?

Comment: You are not clear on the keys? And why don't you try a couple examples and check the results?

Comment: The example in the docs shows it ignores the keys; You can use [arry_diff_assoc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-assoc.php) if you did want to compare at that level

Comment: Yes, it totally ignores the keys, unless you use array_diff_assoc()

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you use :

```
array_diff($array2, $array1);
```

You will be sure that all $array2 values are in the $array1. But if $array1 have values that $array2 don't have, you will not get them.
Besides, array_diff ignore your keys. Exactly that you want !

Answer (score 0):

The `array_diff()` function is used to find the difference of given arrays.

example

```
<?php
    $a1=array("a"=>"red","b"=>"green","c"=>"blue","d"=>"yellow");
    $a2=array("e"=>"red","f"=>"green","g"=>"blue");

    $result=array_diff($a1,$a2);
    print_r($result);
?>
```

Output

```
Array ( [d] => yellow )
```

### In your code

**Errors**

1. ***Invalid array pointers*** `[0]` should come `0`
2. ***Missing `,`*** on end of array elements

php code

```
<?php
    $array1 = array
    (
        0 => 1457543,
        1 => 1457544,
        2 => 1461778,
        3 => 1465640,
        4 => 1473801,
        5 => 1474814,
        6 => 1474815,
        7 => 1475227,
        8 => 1478144,
        9 => 1479478,
        10  => 1480843
    );

    $array2 = array
    (
        0=> 1336623,
        1=> 1457543,
        2=> 1457544,
        3=> 1461778,
        4=> 1465640,
        5=> 1468007,
        6=> 1474814,
        7=> 1474815,
        8=> 1478144,
        9=> 1479478,
        10 => 1480843
    );

    $result=array_diff($array1,$array2);
    print_r($result);
?>
```

**Output**

```
Array ( [4] => 1473801 [7] => 1475227 )
```

[Your Output in phpFiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/fx4s-iugt)